# Android program works in older versions

Tags: android

I recently formatted my computer, but after installing Eclipse and running the program, the app does not look the same as before.

I explain this example with a picture ..

**New**

[image: new]

**Old**

[image: old]

Here is my manifest versions

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="22"
          android:maxSdkVersion="24" />
```

Comment: You are seeing different text styles and widgets. That is to be expected on different Android versions

Comment: No, everthing same. Program api is changed.. Please help..

Comment: Everything does not look the same. You clearly pointed at "New" and "Old"

Comment: A lot of things are changed. For example, when opening program, opening like old api

Comment: Switch is a good example for changing api..

Comment: Right, you have to use [`android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) instead

Comment: I understood you, but you didn't.. Before formatting, there is no error. Why after format, errors came..

Comment: Because you probably imported the code, which downloaded the Support Libraries, which require newer API versions

Comment: But i downloaded all Support Libraries, added project. Project is running but with old api.. i am novice, and i dont find solution for 3 days.. please help.

Comment: Yes, you downloaded them, but that doesn't make the UI use those components.

Comment: So what do I need to run my program for the new API ?

Comment: Your program does run on the new API - the UI just looks different. At least, that is what I understand. If that is the case, then you need to replace some of the Views with the Compat views. Like `Switch` with `SwitchCompat`, for example

Comment: Very thanks.. I using eclipse, if i launch Android Studio and i import project android studio.. Do you think ?

Comment: I would recommend Android Studio because Eclipse is no longer supported, but I bet you'll have the same issues

Comment: Very thanks my friend..

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android Support Libraries.

https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

This way you can get the same theme across all api versions.

Some other useful links:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Migrating-to-the-AppCompat-Library
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Comment: After formatting "View requires API level 14 (current min is 8): <Switch>" error came